# Spring controller inheritance and linked requestbody deserealization problems

Tags: spring-mvc, jackson-databind

My objectmapper not working when I use spring controller & class for requestbody inheritation   .

```
 @JsonTypeInfo(
            use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
            include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY,
            property = "type", visible = true)
    @JsonSubTypes({
            @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = RecipeVersion.class, name = "recipe"),
            @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = DietVersion.class, name = "diet"),
    })
    public interface DocumentVersion {
        Info getInfo();
        void setInfo(Info info);
    }
```

and also

```
@Data
public class DietVersion implements DocumentVersion {
    private LocalizedText warnings;
    private List<DietDay> days = new LinkedList<>();
    private Info info = new Info();

    private String getType() {
        return "diet";
    }
}
```

Ok. I have BaseController for diets and recipes

```
abstract public class BaseController<T extends Document<V>, V extends DocumentVersion> {

    abstract protected BaseService<T, V> getService();

    @PostMapping("/{docId}/version/last")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT)
    public void saveVersion(@PathVariable("docId") String docId, @RequestBody V version, Authentication authentication) {
        getService().replaceLastVersion(docId, version, authentication);
    }
}
```

and some realizations. example for diet

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/diet")
public class DietController extends BaseController<Diet, DietVersion> {

    private final DietService dietService;

    @Autowired
    public DietController(DietService dietService) {
        this.dietService = dietService;
    }

    @Override
    protected DietService getService() {
        return dietService;
    }

    @Override
    public void saveVersion(String docId, DietVersion version, Authentication authentication) {
        super.saveVersion(docId, version, authentication);
    }
}
```

But when I send json with info, days, type ('diet') to '/diet/1/version/last' then I see in debug mode that my DietVersion pure clear and has no any data. Why ?

How to change settings for objectmapper ?

Comment: what if you provide all this in your DietController  class. `public void saveVersion(@PathVariable("docId") String docId, @RequestBody V version, Authentication authentication){`

Comment: @yas Make answer. And I tag this as solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what if you provide all this in your DietController class.

```
public void saveVersion(@PathVariable("docId") String docId, @RequestBody V version, Authentication authentication){
```

Comment: 2 variants: a) delete saveVersionMethod from DietController b) add pathVariable and request body annotations - all works!